# Listening for downloads when application is minimized

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an application that listens for downloads and performs an action upon hearing it. The key here is that I want the application to do this even when it's minimized (like when a user downloads from the browser). The following code does not seem to be tripping the receiver:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    System.out.println("did download");

                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                        String downloadPath = intent.getStringExtra(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI);
                        System.out.println(downloadPath);
                    }

                }
            };

            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


    }



}
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: once you exit the activity your app will lose the reference to the BroadcastReceiver, better to build seperate class for it, and register the reveiver in the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your almost there just move your `BroadcastReceiver` to a separate file . Do what you  want with the received String `downloadPath`. In this example I save it to `SharedPreferences`.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            String downloadPath = intent.getStringExtra(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI);
            editor.putString("downloadPath", downloadPath);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

In your manifest add this and edit the `action`

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver " >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="PUT YOUR ACTION HERE DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Would there be any way to manipulate this solution to work when a download is triggered rather than when it's completed? For example, using DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING?

Comment: Im not that familiar with `DownloadManager`. You could or should maybe create a new question for this. Supply your code again using `MyBroadcastReceiver` because it decouple events and can i'm sure easily be used to reroute what you want

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the broadcast receiver in manifest. More about the differences between the dynamically register and statically register, please see [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: It'd be nice if you provided some quick code as to how to do that.